# Unable to understand the behavior of method `build` in tensorflow keras layers (tf.keras.layers.Layer)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

Layers in tensorflow keras have a method `build` that is used to defer the weights creation to a time when you have seen what the input is going to be. [a layer's build method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#build)

I have a few questions i have not been able to find the answer of:

1. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#layers_are_recursively_composable) it is said that

   > If you assign a Layer instance as attribute of another Layer, the outer layer will start tracking the weights of the inner layer.

What does it mean to track the weights of a layer?

2. The same link also mentions that

   > We recommend creating such sublayers in the **init** method (since the sublayers will typically have a build method, they will be built when the outer layer gets built).

Does it mean that while running the `build` method of child class (self), there will an iteration through all the attributes of `self` and whichever are found to be subclassed from (instances of) `tf.keras.layer.Layer` will have their `build` methods run automatically?

3. I can run this code:

```
class Net(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net()
print(net.variables)
```

But not this:

```
class Net(tf.keras.Model):
  """A simple linear model."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
  def build(self,input_shape):
    super().build()
  def call(self, x):
    return self.l1(x)

net = Net()
print(net.variables)
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the **build** mentioned means, when you build a self-defined tf.keras.Model for example

```
net = Net()
```

then you will get all the `tf.keras.layers.Layer` objects create in `__init__`, and being stored in `net` which is a callable object. In this case, it will become a completed object for TF to train later, this is what it said **to track**. The next time you call `net(inputs)` you'll can get your outputs.

Here is a example of Tensorflow self-defined decoder with attention

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, query, values):
    # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
    # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
    # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
    # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
    query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

    # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
    # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
    score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
        self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

    # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

    # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
    context_vector = attention_weights * values
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

    return context_vector, attention_weights

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, batch_sz):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.dec_units = dec_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.dec_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    # used for attention
    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.dec_units)

  def call(self, x, hidden, enc_output):
    # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(hidden, enc_output)

    # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(x)

    # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

    # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
    output, state = self.gru(x)

    # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
    output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[2]))

    # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
    x = self.fc(output)

    return x, state, attention_weights
```

I have tried to put `tf.keras.layers.Layer` object in `call` and got really poor outcome, guess that was because if you put it in `call` then it will be call multiple times while each time a forward-backward propagation happends.