# Why is it that `input_shape` does not include the batch dimension when passed as an argument to the `Dense` layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In Keras, why is it that `input_shape` does not include the batch dimension when passed as an argument to layers like `Dense` but DOES include the batch dimension when `input_shape` is passed to the `build` method of a model?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([Dense(1, input_shape=[10])])
    model1.summary()

    model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([Dense(1)])
    model2.build(input_shape=[None, 10])  # why [None, 10] and not [10]?
    model2.summary()
```

Is this a conscious choice of API design? If it is, why?

Comment: When you train that model, what you are doing is passing to the model one sample at a time, that is what is happening under the hood, So `Dense` layer will only get a sample of dimension `[10]` each time. `build()` method is a bit messy in my opinion, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818642/unable-to-understand-the-behavior-of-method-build-in-tensorflow-keras-layers) helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the input shape of your model in several different ways. For example by providing one of the following arguments to the first layer of your model:

- `batch_input_shape`: A tuple where the first dimension is the batch size.
- `input_shape`: A tuple that does not include the batch size, e.g., the batch size is assumed to be `None` or `batch_size`, if specified.
- `input_dim`: A scalar indicating the dimension of the input.

In all these cases, Keras is [internally storing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ce0d0a458c87c8c3c541d56bfbea85455e4c7003/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L418) an attribute `_batch_input_size` to build the model.

Regarding the `build` method, my guess is that this is indeed a conscious choice - information about the batch size might be useful to build the model in some (perhaps unthought-of) situations. Therefore, a framework that includes the batch dimension as input to `build` is more generic and complete than a framework that doesn't. Nonetheless, I agree with you that naming the argument `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape` would make everything more consistent.

---

It is also worth mentioning that users rarely need to call the `build` method by themselves. This happens internally when it is needed.  Nowadays, it is even possible to [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871463/keras-sequential-without-providing-input-shape) the `input_shape` argument when creating the model (although methods like `summary` will then not work until the model is built). In this case, Keras is able to infer the input shape from the argument `x` of `fit`.

Answer (score -1):

`input` is not a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` , it's `tf.keras.Input` .
`tf.keras.layers.Dense` inherits from `tf.keras.layers.Layer` while `tf.keras.Input` is only a function .
You shouldn't compare `input` with `tf.keras.layers.Dense`

Comment: The snippet in the question does not use `tf.keras.Input` anywhere explicitly. The question is about the inconsistency in the argument named `input_shape`.

Comment: @Jensun . You can see the ```tf.keras.layers.Layer``` source code and you will find that its subclass doesn't need to  assign the first dim in ```input_shape``` . In fact , it will be set as ```batch_size``` automatically by ```tf.keras``` . It is a good design because it let you set ```batch_size``` conveniently . (you can set ```batch_size``` in ```tf.data``` or ```model.fit```)